# Sandbox error when running nix build on macOS

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nix, macos

I'm trying to get the exercises for week 1 of the plutus pioneer program working. I've installed nix and have set the IOHK caches.

When I try to run `nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core` in the plutus repo I get the following error:

```
 ❮❮❮ nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for Agda entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
builder for '/nix/store/gpkkaj0mcs6wxaknfjm0jh389x8l4gwb-plutus-core-0.1.0.0-coverage-report.drv' failed with exit code 65; last 1 log lines:
  sandbox-exec: pattern serialization length 71571 exceeds maximum (65535)
[0 built (1 failed), 0.0 MiB DL]
```

I'm running this command on commit `ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4`.

I've looked through the [plutus community docs](https://docs.plutus-community.com/) but haven't found any mention of this error.

Has anyone run into this before? What does this mean? Is there a known fix?

EDIT: this also happens on `master` at commit `8ce0d58c0a169f4c8a1104757502f342e750c863`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm on MacOS and some docs that I followed mentioned turning on the sandbox feature by adding

```
sandbox = true
extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
```

to `/etc/nix/nix.conf`.

Removing these two lines eliminated the error.

Comment: I am in the Cohort 3, and following multiple guides as well, macOS i7 Monterey.  Do you still recommend removing those?  I see here it recommends adding, but no others do... https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps#nix-on-macos . I had issues building the client.

Answer (score 1):

I found this `/etc/nix/nix.conf` to work for my macOS i7 Monterey (v12.1).

It was recommended to turn the sandbox FALSE because 'not recommended' per Ref #1 below.

```
    build-users-group = nixbld
    
    substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
    trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=volume
    
    sandbox = false
    extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
    experimental-features = nix-command
    extra-experimental-features = flakes
```

References:

1. [CSE, @angerman, on macOS Monterey i7, what is the best `nix.conf` file to use?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6701/4012)
2. [Github: Status of macOS support in Nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/116341)
3. https://github.com/Til-D/cardano-plutus
4. https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

Comment: Answer could be improved by following these guidelines: [How to reference material written by others](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: tracked down reference source and updated per comment.

Comment: Well done, you get a whole upvote from me!  Sorry I can't do more.

Answer (score 0):

on debian distro, it works fine with all the details mentioned in developers forum. I built it on VS code debian distro with WSL2.  its tricky as sometime u need to execute chmod command as it wont let u access it.