# macOS Monterey i7, what is the best `nix.conf` file to use?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix, macos

Does anyone have the recommended `nix.conf` file to use for **macOS Monterey i7**?

Following a few different tutorials, my current .conf file looks like:

```
build-users-group = nixbld
substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=volume
```

However, https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps#nix-1 for macOS also recommends adding:

```
sandbox = true
extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
```

Any other working steps are appreciated.  I wouldn't follow tutorials for the M1 i'm assuming too.  Thanks!

Ref:
[https://www.punkbit.com/hacking/plutus-developer-environment-setup-on-macos-monterey/]

Answer (score 1):

macOS `nix` setup on x86_64 (Intel, AMD) and aarch64 (Apple Silicon) should be identical.  Running the installer from the [official website](https://nixos.org/download.html), should get you a proper install.

You *do* want to add the iohk substituter to get access to the cached builds:

```
https://hydra.iohk.io
hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ=
```

I'm fairly sure that the iohk.cachix.org instance is defunct (or not updated anymore really). So it should be fairly safe to remove the following

```
https://iohk.cachix.org
iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo=
```

Please don't enable sanboxing on macOS, while that is in principle a good idea, it will lead to crashes with complex nix expressions. See [Status of macOS | nixos/nixpkgs#116341](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/116341)

Comment: This /etc/nix/nix.conf wound up working for me, based on your help, for my masOS i7 v12.1 monterey: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/6745/4012